# Rails Guide for removing nested attributes seems incorrect and gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

The Rails guide says I can use this checkbox to let users delete a nested attribute. It has a typo, doesn't seem to use the builder `addresses_form`, and creates an error when I try to copy it in my app.

Any idea what the correct syntax for a checkbox would be here?

The seemingly incorrect guide is here - Section 9.4 Removing Objects - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#removing-objects

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  Addresses:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |addresses_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box :_destroy%> # This seems wrong and gives error
        <%= addresses_form.label :kind %>
        <%= addresses_form.text_field :kind %>
        ...
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Produces error:

`wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..5)`

Comment: Try changing the affected line to `<%= addresses_form.check_box :_destroy %>`.

Comment: Good catch. The typo's been [fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a7713765#diff-6c86ada7eb016a7b145c128714a8d379R959) and the correction is present in the [Edge Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#removing-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `check_box :_destroy` to `addresses_form.check_box :_destroy`.

There are two methods called `check_box` - one is called on a form object and can be called with a single argument, the other is a view helper and requires at least two arguments.